# Yii disable http cache

Tags: php, caching, yii, browser-cache

How can I disable the http cache on Yii? The browser can't update the view, until I refresh the browser manually.

Is there some like cakephp disableCache()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP's function does

```
$this->header(array(
    'Expires' => 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT',
    'Last-Modified' => gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT",
    'Cache-Control' => 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'
));
```

so maybe you can make a function with:

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
```

and call it when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Check your filters() method inside your controller and/or base controller (if you're using it). There should be something like 'CHttpCacheFilter' in it, just remove that. By default HttpCache isn't enabled.

More details:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/nl/caching.page#http-caching

If you don't use the CHttpCacheFilter, check your .htaccess file, perhaps there is some http caching done as well.